# iOS - Multiple levels of transparency

Tags: ios, view, transparency

In my view hierarchy I have multiple views on top of each other, and I find sometimes that when there are multiple areas of transparency on top of each other, that area becomes black.  What I'd like is to be able to see parts of the base view, despite the fact that there might be 4 or 5 views on top of it.

Is there a known issue with multiple levels of transparency, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The views are all 400px by 320px with a [UIColor clearColor] background color. The alpha is always set to 1.0f.

Comment: I've never had this issue with multiple transparent views on top of eachother.

Comment: Are all the views non-opaque? (That is, is their `opaque` property set to NO?)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `opaque` property of the views to `NO`.